# matrix in python how to remove \n in last line

Tags: python

I write code in python3

```
mat=[]
r,c=input().split()
r=int(r)
c=int(c)
x=0
for i in range(r):
    mat.append([])
    for j in range(c):
        x=x+1
        mat[i].append(x)
        print(mat[i][j], end=" ")
    print()
```

Input:

```
3 1
```

Expected Output:

```
1\n 2\n 3
```

My Output:

```
1\n 2\n 3\n
```

how to correct it please help

Comment: Use the `strip()` function

Comment: where i use strip() in code please help

Answer (score 1):

Assume lastVariable holds `"1\n 2\n 3\n"`. You can reassign

```
lastVariable = lastVariable.rstrip('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout):

```
import sys
mat=[]
r,c=map(int,input().split())
x=0
bool_=False
for i in range(r):
    if bool_:
        print()
    bool_=True
    for j in range(c):
        x=x+1
        mat.append(x)
        sys.stdout.write('%s '%mat[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting a newline at the end of every iteration. Instead, you can output a newline at the beginning of every iteration, but only starting on the second iteration, when the `mat` list is not empty:

```
mat=[]
r,c=input().split()
r=int(r)
c=int(c)
x=0
for i in range(r):
    if mat:
        print()
    mat.append([])
    for j in range(c):
        x=x+1
        mat[i].append(x)
        print(mat[i][j], end=" ")
```

Comment: Hi now small problem left output is 1 \n come     and correct output is 1\n please help

Answer (score 0):

Just keep an if condition at the end of the loop to avoid newline for the last iteration.

```
mat=[]
r,c=input().split()
r=int(r)
c=int(c)
x=0
for i in range(r):
    mat.append([])
    for j in range(c):
        x=x+1
        mat[i].append(x)
        print(mat[i][j], end=" ")
    if i < r-1:
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mat=[]
r,c=raw_input().split()
r=int(r)
c=int(c)
x=0
for i in range(r):
    mat.append([])
    for j in range(c):
        x=x+1
        mat[i].append(x)
print(repr('\n '.join([' '.join(map(str,row)) for row in mat])))
print('\n '.join([' '.join(map(str,row)) for row in mat]))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
input

3 1
'1\n 2\n 3'
1
 2
 3
input 

3 4
'1 2 3 4\n 5 6 7 8\n 9 10 11 12'
1 2 3 4
 5 6 7 8
 9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 0):

hi everyone thanks for support and help i got the correct code is

```
matrix=[]
n,m=input().split()
p=int(n)
q=int(m)
c=1
for i in range(p):
    l=[]
    for j in range(q):
        l.append(c)
        c=c+1
    matrix.append(l)
for i in range(p):
    for j in range(q):
        if j == q-1 and not i == p-1:
            print(matrix[i][j],end=r"")
        else:
            print(matrix[i][j],end=r" ")
    print()
```